# Angular Modal>Ctrl>Service>Ctrl inheritance not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service, angularjs-controller

I am trying to link models to services which will allow me to update global models throughout my app, however it does not seem to be working as anticipated.

I have recently started looking into AngularJS so it is possible I am misunderstanding my code however from what I understand a service will work as an instance as oppose to a factory singleton which should allow me to use a service to control all $scoped models.

I am trying to chain my model like this:

**model:** {{ language.title }}

**>>>** **ctrl1:** $scope.language = langSrvic.store;

**>>>** **srvic:** langSrvic.store = myFactory;

**>>>** **ctrl2:** langSrvic.set('locale', 'fr');

**>>>** language instance store updated (should reflect change in controller 1 model)

**[jsFiddle of my working code](http://jsfiddle.net/3c7ube0s/)**

```js
//Application
var app = angular.module('app',[]);

//Controller 1
app.controller('first', ['$scope', 'language', function($scope, language){
 $scope.language = language.store;
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log($scope.language.title); //My application
        console.log(language.store.title); //Something something french
    }, 1500);
}]);

//Language service
app.service('language', ['i18n', function(i18n){
 return {
  locale: 'en',
  store: i18n['en'],
  set: function(prop, val){
   this[prop] = val;
   this.store = i18n[this.locale];
  }
 }
}]);

//Factory - storing instead of an api temporarily
app.factory('i18n', [function(){
 return {
  en:{
   title: 'My application'
  },
  fr:{
   title: 'Something something french'
  },
 }
}]);

//Controller 2 - changing locale to fr which should update the instance store and so update the first scope
app.controller('second', ['$scope', 'language', function($scope, language){
    language.set('locale', 'fr');
    $scope.language = language.store;
}]);
```

```html
<div ng-controller="first">
    {{ language.title }}
    <div ng-controller="second">
        {{ language.title }}
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referencing a different `store` object:

```
set: function(prop, val){
    this[prop] = val;
    this.store = i18n[this.locale]; // this line sets language.store to the new object but Controller 1 is referencing the old one
}
```

See updated fiddle for a fix: http://jsfiddle.net/3c7ube0s/1/

Comment: Thank you, I have no idea how I missed this :) will accept in a few minutes when its available.